# Twitter Bootstrap and <p> default height: why 28px?

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, paragraph

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap. Everything goes fine, but `<p>some text with the font-size of 50px</p>` jumps out of the parent `<div>`. Once I remove bootstrap.min.css as a stylesheet, everything is OK.

Seems like Twitter Bootstrap applies some properties (heights, vertical paddings) on paragraphs because there are no additional properties for p tag in my own css file.

How to fix all `<p>` so that `<p>Paragraph text could be any size and not jump out of the parent div</p>`?

OK, here is an update:

```
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
  <style>
    p {
      border:1px solid red;
      font-size:55px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <p>The text of more than 18 px is out of the red border if bootstrap.min.css connected </p>
</body>
```

Please do not forget to connect bootstrap.min.css to test it.

Comment: Bootstrap applies just min-height on some elements. In case of <p> element, there is no max-height limit. But if you use big font sizes, try to change line-height on that paragraph. (default is line-height: 18px;)

Comment: the only css bootstrap applies to `p` is a `margin-bottom` of `9px`, and inherits a `font-size` of `13px` and `line-height` of `18px` from `body`. Perhaps post some example code.

Answer (score 1):

as others said, the only (important) thing bootstrap does to a `p` is:

```
font-size: 13px;
line-height: 18px;
```

both inherited from `body`. the easiest fix for that is to replace the [line-height](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/line-height) value with a [font-relative value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/length#Font-relative_length):

```
p{
  line-height: 1.4em;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Changing all paragraph elements in your site to a font-size of 55px is a bad idea.  Don't overwrite a base element with minimal-use customizations.  I think a better solution for you would be to make your own custom paragraph class and use that when you need large text.

```
p.large {
    border: 1px solid red;
    font-size: 55px;
    line-height: 60px;
}

<p class="large">some text with the font-size of 55px</p>
```

Comment: I just showed is as a short example without using classes. But, thank you for this notice.